# Mysql: how to create a query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: one named `document` and the other `cDoc`. The table "document" has these columns:

```
idDoc(primary key)
nameFile
type
depth
```

The table `cDoc` has these columns:

```
idDoc(foreign key)
idContDoc(primary key)
tag
content
```

I would like to create a query to get the data: idContDoc,content(from table cDoc) and nameFile(from table document). I tried with:

```
select idContDoc,content from cDoc
```

How can I get the also recover its "nameFile" of the document table?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because shows no research effort.

Comment: I spaced out your columns for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using command `JOIN`. You should really read documentation on SQL and\or some turorial in the internet, before asking this.

```
SELECT cDoc.idContDoc,cDoc.content,document.nameFile 
FROM cDoc 
JOIN document ON document.idDoc=cDoc.idContDoc`
```

Comment: If you intent your code with four spaces, it gets syntax highlighting. Otherwise, good job beating me to the punch, +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.nameFile , b.idContDoc , b.content  
FROM document a
JOIN cDoc b ON a.idDoc = b.idDoc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT idContDoc, content, nameFile FROM document, cDoc 
WHERE document.idDoc = cDoc.idDoc
```

Using simply FROM and WHERE is usually easier for SQL beginners than JOINs.